# Quality of custom slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should I be using `this` more, instead of `slider`? Am I making any serious no-no's here, and is there a better design I should implement? I'm up for any pointers :)

```
slider = {
                selector : '#slider',
                init : function() {
                        $('#slider').hover(function(e){
                            slider.toggle();
                        });

                    $(document).bind('click', function(e){
                        slider.lock.unlock();
                        slider.state.collapse();
                    });

                    $('#slider').bind('click', function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        slider.lock.lock();
                    })
                },
                toggle : function() {
                    if (!this.lock.isLocked) {
                        this.state.toggle();
                    }
                },
                lock : {
                    isLocked   : false,
                    lock : function() {
                        this.isLocked = true;
                    },
                    unlock : function() {
                        this.isLocked = false;
                    }
                },
                state : {
                    isExtended : false,
                    toggle : function() {
                        if (this.isExtended===true) {
                            this.collapse();
                        } else {
                            this.extend();
                        }
                    },
                    extend : function() {
                        this.isExtended = true;
                        $('#slider').stop().animate({'left':'-5px'}, 'slow');
                    },
                    collapse : function() {
                        this.isExtended = false;
                        $('#slider').stop().animate({'left':'-210px'}, 'slow');
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **You never use `slider.selector`**, so what's the point?
2. **jQuery instances should be "cached"**, otherwise you are creating new jQuery object each time you call `$()` function.
3. **This code permits only one slider per page**. What if you need more? Will you copy-paste the whole thing?
4. **This is not configurable** at all. You have to change the objects source, just to change the way animation works.
5. **jQuery is not really necessary here**. You actually need it only for animations, which is not jQuery's strong point.
6. **Slider object ends up in global scope.**

Answer (score 0):

All your `slider` calls are inside the jQuery callbacks, so they use their own context. For example, in this callback:

```
$('#slider').hover(function(e){
   slider.toggle();
});
```

`this` would refer to the #slider DOM element, not your slider object.

At the jQuery help page they suggest a [basic Module pattern](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/#the-module-pattern) that would help you a lot designing your plugin slider.